# C# web application - waiting for localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am struggeling with my web application. When I debug it using VS2008, it keeps on saying waiting for localhost in the web browser for ages !! I have restarted it, and still the same thing. I am implementing a web application that generates random numbers whenever a button is clicked, adds them up and shows the total.

I would really appreciate your recommendations.

Thanks !!

CODE:

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

     private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
     {
        Random random = new Random();

        return random.Next(min, max);

     }


        protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int number = RandomNumber(1, 10);
            int number2 = RandomNumber(1, 10);
            int total = number + number2;
            Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(number);
            Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(number2);
            TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(total);

           try
           {
            while (total <= 18)
            {
                int number3 = RandomNumber(1, 10);
                total = number + number2 + number3;
                Label4.Text = Convert.ToString(number3);
                TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
            }}
            catch (Exception ex)
           {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }



        }
    }
```

Comment: Without code, it is hard to help. Perhaps an infinite loop somewhere?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the code, and what sequence of events is leading to this response? Is it simply right after debugging, or is it after a button press, etc?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a firewall issue, make sure the VS development server is running ok (in the tray). You might have to disable your firewall or AV for a min or two to test.

Comment: @CrisCarew It is right after debugging and sometimes after I press the button

Comment: @LillyPop It might be I'll check, thanks.

Comment: @LillyPop Nope, its not the firewall

Comment: sometimes it works, but it reaches a point where if I press the button lets say for 6 times, then it stops working and comes back again to the "waiting for localhost"

Comment: a simple debug step of your code it will make you find your self :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in many cases.  The while loop will only break out if the total is greater than 18.  If you get the random numbers, for example, number1 = 2 and number2 = 3 than you have an infinite loop since number3 can never be greater than 10.

2 + 3  + (1 through 10) = infinite loop.

Comment: Also, since you're creating nee instances of Random all the time, your random numbers are not random very much (Random is seeded with the same value).

Comment: Then how do I amend the code, meaning what should I change in it ??

Comment: @Humam Shbib - I would create a private member variable for the Random instance and just call it so it is seeded once.